# Create zero-length file with custom extension

Tags: ffmpeg

For a class I am creating a custom codec called .utah.  The whole idea is to immerse ourselves in a large and unfamiliar code base.  So far this has been very fun, and to start we have created a .utah decoder file that will simply print hello world out to the console.  The problem is, if we take a .png file and rename it with a .utah, ffmpeg won't route it (at all) and if we create a .utah file using a text editor, it will save as a text file even with a .utah extension.

The question is how do we create an empty file with our own extension (in this case .utah) to test that what will happen when we pass a file to ffplay, to ensure it's properly routing to our file.  More concisely, can we create a dummy .utah file that is empty but has a

Comment: Did you forget to complete the last sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're working on a linux system (please use the appropriate tags). If so, you have two options for creating empty files with whatever name and extension you need.

```
touch filename.ext
```

or

```
echo -n "" > filename.ext
```

Added reference to extension based on @HairoftheDog's comment.

Comment: more precisely `touch filename.utah`

Comment: Thank you kindly, my partner and I had tried this.  Upon further inspection, something is wrong with our decoder implementation, because if we did something like

`touch filename.png`

ffplay would work.  But doing that to generate a .utah file does not.  This indicates that our decoder isn't working properly yet.